# Formula to display price based on input number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Is there a formula that will display a price based on the number in a cell?

The idea:

IF cell is = 1, the price is $99

IF cell is > 1, 99 for the first and add 50 for each additional number after 1.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need an if statement at all -- but I don't know excel so perhaps you can't do what I'm thinking, which is something like `price = 99 + (50 * (cell - 1))`.

Comment: If the cell is `123`, then do you want `99 + 50 + 50` or `99 + 2(50) + 3(50)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on HashPsi, you need to check to make sure that the cell has a number higher than 0. And to default to 0 when it is empty.

A1 is the reference cell.

```
=IF(A1>0, (99+(A1-1)*50), 0)
```